# Find limit of $x_n = a ^ {x_{n-1}}$

Tags: calculus

We have $n > 1, a > 0, x_1 = 1$ and sequence $x_n = a ^ {x_{n-1}}$

Find $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$ for all values of $a.$

How can we solve this. Suppose we can prove that sequnce converges using Cauchy theorem for fundamental sequence. Also we should consider two possible ways: $a > 1$ and $a < 1.$ I think in the case of $a > 1$ sequence hasn't finit limit. But how to find exact limits? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convergence of the sequence $x_{n+1} = a^{x_n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3428506/convergence-of-the-sequence-x-n1-ax-n)

Comment: Yes, partly, my task in addition requires finding all limits.

Comment: To find the limit you have to use Lambert W-function, since it's $L=a^L$